# Prestashop cant login in admin

Tags: redirect, authentication, admin, prestashop

Several days ago I couldn't access the admin panel on my site based on prestashop platform.
After entering login and password, I was redirected to login page again and everything repeated.

The site is hosted on a dedicated server, where some other prestashop sites I am developing are hosted too. After trying to access the admin panel on these sites I get the same "error".

What do you think, what is problem?

Prestashop ver.: 1.4.7.3 and 1.4.8.2

Server: CentOs, PHP

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here is some things you can try :

**1/ Clear your browser cache and your cookies**

**2/ Try using Firefox instead of Chrome** (which seems have some unexpected problems)

**3/ Check `PS_SHOP_DOMAIN` and `PS_SHOP_DOMAIN_SSL` in `ps_configuration` table**

**4/ Manually clear smarty cache** : remove all files from `tools/smarty/compile` and `tools/smarty/cache`

**5/ Disable the IP check** in `classes/Cookie.php` (this can causes many issues with dynamics IP) :
in `isLoggedBack()`, remove or comment the fourth condition :

`AND (!isset($this->_content['remote_addr']) OR $this->_content['remote_addr'] == ip2long(Tools::getRemoteAddr()) OR !Configuration::get('PS_COOKIE_CHECKIP'))`

**6/ Make the expire time shorter for cookies** (IE can have issues with longest time cookies) : in `classes/Cookie.php` constructor,

set : `$this->_expire = isset($expire) ? (int)($expire) : (time() + 3600);`

instead of `$this->_expire = isset($expire) ? (int)($expire) : (time() + 1728000);`

Comment: For PS 1.5; `5/ Disable the IP check`: you can instead of manually editing core files go to `Administration > Preferences` and change `Check the IP address on the cookie` to `no` .. same thing to 6/

Comment: +1 for the Firefox suggestion! Chrome seems to just do nothing after a successful login...

Comment: #5 solved it for me - i have 2 internet connection, the issue was happening only on one of them, wander why...

Comment: @UnLoCo. Indeed, using other browser will let you made that change via admin panel.

Comment: Deleting the cookies for my site fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Thanks you fore response !

Comment: 5 : Change core code is never a good idea, and will be erased by updates. You should change the configuration value in the database for PS_COOKIE_CHECKIP in ps_configuration

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue after adding a NGINX as reverse proxy in front of my Apache web server.

The problem was from the « *Check the IP address on the cookie* » parameter set to « *yes* ». Since i was locked out from admin and could not change it, i did it directly in the database with this SQL request :

```
UPDATE ps_configuration SET value = 0 WHERE name='PS_COOKIE_CHECKIP';
```

PS : `ps_` is my table prefix, you may adapt it to your settings.

Comment: This is fast. A good solution may be to add a if clause and put few code lines to check for (in example) $_REQUEST["letmein"] ... so you can enter the panel and enable/disable the cookie check for that intance. Disabling forever is not a good idea.

Comment: It's ok for me :)

Comment: This is most reliable solution and will work for all scenarios. This issue could be introduced when a load balancer is set in place and BO is accessed by more than one IP. 
But security-wise, it may not be most correct solution because the whole point of having a secure connection is void.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me. But I also needed to disable the "Gamification - customers expertise" module.

Answer (score 3):

I spent a lot of time debugging this. Installed prestashop locallly on my computer. I my case the following, you should manually navigate to the following:

```
< domain >/admin/index.php
```

Comment: thank you very much, you solved it for my case... on fedora 32

Answer (score 2):

For solution try this:

- Open; phpMyAdmin, ps_configuration table
- Find, PS_COOKIE_CHECKIP and set it as 0
- Clear all cache then try again, probably it will be solved.

You can think that it is related to IP/network issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue as everyone else.

I was able to login via IE but not firefox.

What I did to remedy the issue was go into cookie manager and delete all the cookies.

I know it sounds cliche but nothing else worked.

I searched for my site name and looked at the cookie, it was dated long but no longer active. My guess was I corrupted the cookie or maybe they do IP matching, because in the middle of using the admin panel, I switched to my phone browser to check something. Upon return, it would just loop the login page, no error.

I think they need to fix the issue from the software standpoint.

Regardless, after I deleted all the cookies associated with my site, I got right back in no problem. It also resolved an issue I was having with www.mysite.com and mysite.com. I was talking to tech support because sometimes it would work and other times it wouldn't. Maybe the cookie also stores which variant of www/non was used for dynamic linking. My DNS was allowed time to resolve and tech support blamed that but it wasn't that.

Don't just clear cookies, go manually delete the ones for your site. When I used the clear cookies, it didn't delete a lot of cookies. I found that my site still had 9 cookies set AFTER the clear cookies. Whether that was my error or something else, I won't know.

Good luck to all and thanks for the other suggestions. If it returns, I'll go into the other suggestions and report back.

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me: in the adminstration>preferences control panel, set "Check the Cookies IP address" to "No."

http://xbfish.com/tag/auto-logout/

Answer (score 1):

I use prestashop 1.4.8.2
I just debuged my back office login loop by changing admin/login.php
Just remove seemingly useless conditions in following code.

```
if ((empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) OR strtolower($_SERVER['HTTPS']) == 'off')
     AND Configuration::get('PS_SSL_ENABLED'))
```

Change with

```
 if (!Configuration::get('PS_SSL_ENABLED'))
```

I also cleared cookie and bam it worked. I don't know if it will mess other stuff but I can AT LAST get in my back office.
Peace!!

Answer (score 0):

There are some possible things that could have happened to prevent your old passwords from working. One could be that your _COOKIE_KEY_ changed.

You can try to use the following script to generate a new password hash. You can then replace it in the database in the xxxx_employee table (where xxxx_ is your table prefix). I hope that works for you. In any case: keep a backup of your old hashes.

Here is the small script:

```
<?php
require(dirname(__FILE__).'/config/config.inc.php');
echo Tools::encrypt($_REQUEST["pw"]);
```

Don't forget to remove the script from your server once your done!

Answer (score 0):

Open the app/config/parameters.php - for Presta 1.7 (both on homepage and hosting when site was moved to)  and compare values (example from my parameters.php):

```php
'cookie_key' => 'ii90g4PzGzL7X7WqTSfwvbCZh9TwGKrueL8sdkwMjssnTTYERDuXaMaW',
'cookie_iv' => '6CxmBHXG',
'new_cookie_key' => 'def00000e5be70ebce6b91c104e594a3fc57b027b6f56eb4cdb4f6b3a0b0fd3ee4940b5e9238347fdd8040b6913084a917142fa2fac7ca73622380ce8ebd3570dd333faa',
```

In my case that did the job

Answer (score -1):

I know this is old but it may help someone, turn errors on by opening /config/config.inc.php.

Look for the line:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'off');
```

change it to:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
```

EDIT: changed a seemingly typo

Comment: This doesn't apply in any way.

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes I get this error when I configured shop domain with non-www and I try to access with www, for example. I like to force all users to have the same url, so I force at .htaccess to enter with www:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: In case that domain matters will not affect. In case that domain doesn't matter, this will not solve anyway.

Answer (score -1):

In case you've moved prestashop from a local version or from another domain, in addition of the classic.

```
update ps_configuration table set value="www.myshop.com" where name ="PS_SHOP_DOMAIN";

update ps_configuration table set value="www.myshop.com" where name ="PS_SHOP_DOMAIN_SSL";
```

Check the table called `ps_shop_url`, and update `domain` and `domain_ssl` field, and `physical_url` as well.

Example:

```
update ps_shop_url set domain='www.myshop.com', domain_ssl='www.myshop.com', physical_url='/';
```

Comment: This doesnt apply in any way