# I Can't Reach Prestashop Back Office Because of Redirection

Tags: apache, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I got a problem when moving my Prestashop 1.6 site from dev machine that using XAMPP to the staging server. The front end of the shop is working fine. However when I am trying to access the back office at  `dev.mydomain.com/adminxxx`, it is always redirected to `index.php?controller=AdminLogin&token=43f1809e717c514333c85d3303db0811` and blank. I had enabled the debug profiler, and I got error `Caught Redirection index.php?controller=AdminLogin&token=43f1809e717c514333c85d3303db0811` message.

It costs me 2 days for the fixing effort with no luck. I've tried several ways:

- http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/prestashop-16/blank-screen
- [Prestashop cant login in admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11335073/prestashop-cant-login-in-admin)
- [Moving guide from Prestashop.com](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/System+Administrator+Guide)

These are my staging server environment:

- Ubuntu 16.04
- Apache 2.4.18
- PHP 5.6.24
- MySQL 5.5

Below is my Apache `virtual host` settings:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@dev.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mydomain/
    ServerName dev.mydomain.com
    <Directory /var/www/html/mydomain/>
        Options FollowSymLinks Indexes MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/mydomain.com-error_log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/mydomain.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

And this is the `.htaccess` file:

```
# ~~start~~ Do not remove this comment, Prestashop will keep automatically the code outside this comment when .htaccess will be generated again
# .htaccess automaticaly generated by PrestaShop e-commerce open-source solution
# http://www.prestashop.com - http://www.prestashop.com/forums

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_env.c>
    SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine on


#Domain: dev.mydomain.com
RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/]
RewriteRule ^api$ api/ [L]

RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

# Images
RewriteRule ^([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$1$2$3.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$1$2$3$4.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$1$2$3$4$5.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$1$2$3$4$5$6.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$8/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9$10.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^c/([0-9]+)(\-[\.*_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/c/$1$2$3.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^c/([a-zA-Z_-]+)(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/c/$1$2.jpg [L]
# AlphaImageLoader for IE and fancybox
RewriteRule ^images_ie/?([^/]+)\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$ js/jquery/plugins/fancybox/images/$1.$2 [L]

# Dispatcher
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}index.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>

AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
AddType font/ttf .ttf
AddType font/otf .otf
AddType application/x-font-woff .woff
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|svg)$">
        Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

#If rewrite mod isn't enabled
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?controller=404

# ~~end~~ Do not remove this comment, Prestashop will keep automatically the code outside this comment when .htaccess will be generated again
```

I put the actual code under `/home/deploy/public_html/mydomain/` and do `ln -s /home/deploy/public_html/mydomain /var/www/html/mydomain`.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now the staging environment is working, after I re-installed to the brand new server. I don't know what's going on here, at last, the website works. Weird.

Comment: did you ever install prestashop from localhost? 
i have the same problem