# Cant login in prestashop v1.6.1.4 backend (admin) site

Tags: php, cookies, prestashop, backend, prestashop-1.6

If i try to login to the backend the site redirects to the login page. No error is shown.
The issue is similar to this post: [Prestashop cant login in admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11335073/prestashop-cant-login-in-admin)

But none of the solutions helped and are for an earlier version of Prestashop.

The problem seems to be sort of random or with multiple causes.

1) If i clear all the cookies, some times starts to work again, but then start fail again. Other times i clear the cookies and it doesnt help.

2) Some times it fails for http:, but it works for https. Some times it doesnt work for https neither.

3) Some times it works from IE, but not from chrome. Some times neither by IE. Same happens if i try by Chrome private mode.

Previous to this problem:

1) I updated all the modules. (I didnt reverted this becouse it is complicated)

2) i incremented the memory_limit and the max_time_execution in php configuration. (I reverted this but it didnt help)

Also, maybe is related or maybe not, but previous to this problem when i tried to save a product modification some times it didnt save and redirects to product edit page. This is also random, maybe after 2 attemps work, some times after 3 attemps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by PrestaAlba it is related to a bug caused by an update in recent browsers. [Getting Rid of Synchronous XHRs](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/01/Getting-Rid-of-Synchronous-XHRs), Synchronous ajax requests are now blocked by a majority of browsers.

You then have 3 choices to solve this:

- You can download an older version of your browser
- You can upgrade to the latest version of Prestashop (as mentioned by PrestaAlba)
- You can apply the modification in [this Pull Request](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/pull/6749/files?w=1) to your store without having to upgrade Prestashop.

Comment: It seems good!! Im not 100% sure if its soved becouse it is sort of "random". I used the 3rd option to avoid the prestashop update and it seems t obe working.

Comment: If it solved your issue, won't you mind accepting this answer to mark this thread as solved? [how does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: There is one user that can login, but when he tries to access the orders section it redirects to the login page. If he tries the admin home page link, he can access (so the system doesnt log out him), but the orders link redirects to the login page again.... any idea??? Maybe there is some file missed in the pull request???

Answer (score 0):

Update to last 1.6 stable Prestashop version. There is a bug related with web browsers updates that it fixed from Prestashop 1.6.10 version on.

Good luck.