# Prestashop admin logs out of the application soon after logging in

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I justed installed a new `Prestashop` instance and after deleting the install folder, I hit `http://example.com/admin` and it redirects to `http://example.com/admin584l2x0fo`. After logging into the admin panel, the very next click takes me out of the application and asks to login again. There is hardly a second gap between the login and the next click. Why is this happening?

I have seen some answers asking to change the settings in the admin panel. But I'm not able to do any action in the admin panel.

Comment: Please check this https://bobcares.com/blog/prestashop-admin-login-problem/ also check this

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11335073/prestashop-cant-login-in-admin

Answer (score 0):

Running the below query solved the issue for me

```
UPDATE ps_configuration SET value = 0 WHERE name='PS_COOKIE_CHECKIP';
```